# How to recursively rename a directory tree to valid Windows filenames?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, filesystems

I am trying to copy a number of directories containing MS-DOS games from a Linux to a Windows computer. However, I am getting a `[WinError 267] The directory name is invalid`.

Here is a listing of a few of these directories:

```
$ ls -d *:* | sort -R | head
Commander Keen 2: The Earth Explodes/
1942: The Pacific Air War/
Super Solvers: Treasure Galaxy/
Life and Death 2: The Brain/
Deja Vu 2: Lost In Las Vegas/
Hard Drivin' 2: Drive Harder/
RoboMaze 2: The Lobby/
Dune 2: The Building of a Dynasty/
Blake Stone: Planet Strike/
Star Trek: First Contact/
```

I suspect the `:` in these directory names are causing this error, because [they are invalid characters in Windows filenames](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

However, since I cannot guarantee that the `:` is the only invalid character used, I am looking for a way to recursively rename all files and directories to valid Windows filenames, substituting the invalid characters for valid ones.

What Linux command lets me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the `rename` command. Install via:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

`rename` uses Perl to make powerful replace commands, but in this case a simple regex replace will do - something like:

```
rename 's/[<>:"\\|\?*]/-/g;' *
```

The above will replace the characters inside the square brackets with the minus sign. The `g` means replace all of them, not just the first occurrence. If you want something more complex, you could replace some characters with minus and some with underscores, e.g.: `rename 's/[<>:]/-/g; s/["\\|\?*]/_/g;' *`

The above will only fix files and directories in the *current* directory. To recursively fix subdirectories and files too, use `find`:

```
find -depth -execdir rename 's/[<>:"\\|\?*]/-/g;' '{}' +
```

In the above example, `find` will run `rename` for every item in or under the current directory, doing a depth-first search.

Comment: Mind this: [What's with all the renames: `prename`, `rename`, `file-rename`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618) Different distros [may provide different utilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78645/108618) named `rename` and syntax that works with one may fail (or give unexpected results) with another.